# LUT2 symbol has input signal which will be trimmed - can't find the solution

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

In my project two modules cannot work with each other.

The first one is

http://pastebin.com/hcwrWg11

and second:

http://pastebin.com/Lm6ZGGsU

The deal is, I want to plug 'A' and 'B' from 'maszyna2' to 'a' and 'b' from 'Liczby' and I got errors:

### Section 1 - Errors

ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<0>1" (output signal=q_0_OBUF) has
   input signal "XLXN_238" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map
   Report File for details about why the input signal will become undriven.

ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<15>1" (output signal=q_15_OBUF) has
   input signal "XLXN_238" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map
   Report File for details about why the input signal will become undriven.

ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<16>1" (output signal=q_16_OBUF) has
   input signal "XLXN_238" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map
   Report File for details about why the input signal will become undriven.

ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<17>1" (output signal=q_17_OBUF) has
   input signal "XLXN_238" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map
   Report File for details about why the input signal will become undriven.

ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<18>1" (output signal=q_18_OBUF) has
   input signal "XLXN_238" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map
   Report File for details about why the input signal will become undriven.

ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<19>1" (output signal=q_19_OBUF) has
   input signal "XLXN_238" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map
   Report File for details about why the input signal will become undriven.

ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<1>1" (output signal=q_1_OBUF) has
   input signal "XLXN_238" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map
   Report File for details about why the input signal will become undriven.

ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<2>1" (output signal=q_2_OBUF) has
   input signal "XLXN_238" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map
   Report File for details about why the input signal will become undriven.

ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<3>1" (output signal=q_3_OBUF) has
   input signal "XLXN_238" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map
   Report File for details about why the input signal will become undriven.

ERROR:MapLib:979 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<4>1" (output signal=q_4_OBUF) has
   input signal "XLXN_238" which will be trimmed. See Section 5 of the Map
   Report File for details about why the input signal will become undriven.

ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<0>1" (output signal=q_0_OBUF) has an
   equation that uses input pin I1, which no longer has a connected signal.
   Please ensure that all the pins used in the equation for this LUT have
   signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the Map Report File for
   details on which signals were trimmed).

ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<15>1" (output signal=q_15_OBUF) has an
   equation that uses input pin I1, which no longer has a connected signal.
   Please ensure that all the pins used in the equation for this LUT have
   signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the Map Report File for
   details on which signals were trimmed).

ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<16>1" (output signal=q_16_OBUF) has an
   equation that uses input pin I1, which no longer has a connected signal.
   Please ensure that all the pins used in the equation for this LUT have
   signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the Map Report File for
   details on which signals were trimmed).

ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<17>1" (output signal=q_17_OBUF) has an
   equation that uses input pin I1, which no longer has a connected signal.
   Please ensure that all the pins used in the equation for this LUT have
   signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the Map Report File for
   details on which signals were trimmed).

ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<18>1" (output signal=q_18_OBUF) has an
   equation that uses input pin I1, which no longer has a connected signal.
   Please ensure that all the pins used in the equation for this LUT have
   signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the Map Report File for
   details on which signals were trimmed).

ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<19>1" (output signal=q_19_OBUF) has an
   equation that uses input pin I1, which no longer has a connected signal.
   Please ensure that all the pins used in the equation for this LUT have
   signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the Map Report File for
   details on which signals were trimmed).

ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<1>1" (output signal=q_1_OBUF) has an
   equation that uses input pin I1, which no longer has a connected signal.
   Please ensure that all the pins used in the equation for this LUT have
   signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the Map Report File for
   details on which signals were trimmed).

ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<2>1" (output signal=q_2_OBUF) has an
   equation that uses input pin I1, which no longer has a connected signal.
   Please ensure that all the pins used in the equation for this LUT have
   signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the Map Report File for
   details on which signals were trimmed).

ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<3>1" (output signal=q_3_OBUF) has an
   equation that uses input pin I1, which no longer has a connected signal.
   Please ensure that all the pins used in the equation for this LUT have
   signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the Map Report File for
   details on which signals were trimmed).

ERROR:MapLib:978 - LUT2 symbol "XLXI_59/q<4>1" (output signal=q_4_OBUF) has an
   equation that uses input pin I1, which no longer has a connected signal.
   Please ensure that all the pins used in the equation for this LUT have
   signals that are not trimmed (see Section 5 of the Map Report File for
   details on which signals were trimmed).

Section 2 - Warnings -------------------- WARNING:Security:42 - Your software subscription period has lapsed. Your current version of Xilinx tools will continue to function, but you no longer qualify for Xilinx software updates or new releases.

Section 3 - Informational ------------------------- INFO:Security:54 - 'xc3s500e' is a WebPack part. INFO:MapLib:562 - No environment variables are currently set.

Section 4 - Removed Logic Summary ---------------------------------    1 block(s) removed    2 block(s) optimized away    1 signal(s) removed

Section 5 - Removed Logic -------------------------

The trimmed logic reported below is either:    1. part of a cycle    2. part of disabled logic    3. a side-effect of other trimmed logic

The signal "XLXN_238" is unused and has been removed.  Unused block "XLXI_62/next_state<0>" (ROM) removed.

Optimized Block(s): TYPE   BLOCK GND   XST_GND VCC   XST_VCC

To enable printing of redundant blocks removed and signals merged, set the detailed map report option and rerun map.

Comment: What does your instantiating entity/architecture look like? Specifically, what does q connect to, since a and b don't seem to be the problem...

Comment: defining "q" as OUT instead of INOUT might already solve the problem... otherwise please post the instantiation code too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that A and B never change.

This is because in your 'maszyna2' file:

```
PROCESS(ABC_LOG);
  BEGIN
    A <= AB_a;
    B <= AB_b;
    L <= LICZBA;
END PROCESS;
```

A and B get assigned the value when an event occurs with the ABC_LOG signal.

```
process2 : process (clk)
               begin
              ABC_LOG <= not ABC_LOG;
```

ABC_LOG changes everytime there's an event in the clk signal.
However, ABC_LOG has never been initialized. This means that ABC_LOG will never change.

Also, since you didn't state the requirement for the change in 'process2', all signals inside that process will be update in both clock edges (rising and falling). While this is possible, it's not a good idea to have a dual edge clock as I'm not sure that the board you're targeting at can properly handle it. I'd suggest you to add

```
if rising_edge( clk ) then
  ...
end if;
```

statement encapsulating your process2.